# VS C++ Issue with InvokeRequired / delegate void

Tags: c++-cli, serial-port, invoke

I am new to C++ and Im using VS2010.
Could someone check the code below and help to solve it? Everytime the function `UpdateDataGrid(unsigned char CANPacket[15])`
is called the following message is shown in a new window and the application closes.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Object of type 'System.Byte' cannot be converted to type 'System.Byte*'.
```

I have to use `unsinged char` data type and not `String^` in this project.
Is there any way to correct my code?

```
//Piece of my code

namespace VCCDC {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    delegate void UpdateDataGridCallback(unsigned char CanPacket[15]);


    private: void UpdateDataGrid(unsigned char CANPacket[15]) {

        if (this->dataGridView1->InvokeRequired) {

            UpdateDataGridCallback^ d = gcnew UpdateDataGridCallback(this,&VCCDC::Form1::UpdateDataGrid);
            this->Invoke(d,gcnew unsigned char(CANPacket[15]));
        }

        else {
            //Update dataGridView1 with new data

        }

    }
}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
this->Invoke(d,gcnew unsigned char(CANPacket[15]));
```

to

```
this->Invoke(d,CANPacket));
```

You already have an `unsigned char` pointer, pass it through. With `gcnew` you intent to create another one, which is unnecessary.

Also error caused by this `gcnew` line. You have to construct the `Byte*` with a `Byte` parameter. Yours is `Byte*` too.